# Can i change accent color (AppCompat) programmatically?

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-styles

I have:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/myColor</item>
</style>
```

But I want to allow the user to change the accent color. Can I do it with AppCompat?

Comment: If you're using AppCompat, you should define colorAccent in your theme instead of android:colorAccent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No you can't, because the accent color is defined in the theme and themes are read-only in Android.

The only thing you can do is switch themes or set the color of each component manually.

**Note**: you can apply a theme to a portion of UI instead of the whole Activity in order to change the accent color (or other things) locally. To do so, you can use the `android:theme` attribute in your XML layout with the AppCompat library, or you can inflate a layout by providing a `ContextThemeWrapper` as context to your `LayoutInflater`.

Comment: Ok, how set the color of component?

Comment: It depends on the component, it's not always possible to  set it programmatically.